# Como executar o PHP no modo interativo?

Tags: php, shell, linha-de-comando

Como faço pra executar o php na linha de comando, sem necessidade de usar um script como argumento.

Exemplo com script:

```
> php index.php
```

Eu já sei como executar uma determinada função ou código assim:

```
> php -r "echo 12346;"
```

Mas  existe alguma maneira de fazer isso interativamente (como no python, por exemplo)?

Algo semelhante a esse exemplo:

```
> php 

> echo 1;
> 1
> print_r(array());
> array(){}
```

Existe isso em PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar assim:

```
C:\>php -a 
Interactive mode enabled 

<?php 
echo "Hello, world!"; 
?> 
^Z 
Hello, world!
```

Para funcionar com `<?php ?>`, primeiro você ativa o modo interativo, digita o `<?php echo "Hello, world!"; ?>` aperta ENTER depois CTR+Z

Veja mais em: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#105729

Comment: No meu só funcionou sem o `<?php ?>`

Comment: Para funcionar com `<?php ?>`, primeiro você ativa o modo interativo, digita o `<?php echo "Hello, world!"; ?>` aperta ENTER depois CTR+Z

Comment: que qui tem de legal nesse modo interativo ? e tipo um playground do Xcode ?

Answer (score 2):

O modo iterativo do PHP não funciona muito bem em todos os sistemas (Windows).

Nesses casos gosto de utilizar o [PsySh](http://psysh.org/). Além de executar em modo iterativo, ele incluí funções como autocomplete, suporte a namespaces, consulta de documentação, entre outros.

Eu instalo ele via composer, como dependência global:

```
composer global require psy/psysh:@stable
```

Answer (score 1):

Para executar o PHP em modo interativo, basta usar a opção `-a`, desta forma:

`php -a` ou `php.exe -a` (se usar Windows)

(desde que o executável do php esteja em seu PATH)

Essa e todas as demais formas de execução do PHP estão descritas aqui:

http://rberaldo.com.br/diferentes-formas-execucao-php/